# Query to show "standard" theme first, then rest of the results

Tags: php, mysql

I have following query to show a list of installed themes. But users can make one theme as standard and I wonder if there is a way to pin the standard theme at the top?

Example:

```
Design 1 
Design 2 (Standard)
```

Design 2 is marked as standard, and should be visible at top and not everywhere else.

```
Design 2 (Standard)
Design 1
Design 3
Design 4
```

SQL/PHP

```
     $find_themes = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM installed_designs WHERE u_id='$user[id]' order by tmp_id desc");
     while($themes = mysqli_fetch_array($find_themes))
     {
         echo '<tr>
         <td>'.$themes["name"].'</td>
         <td>'; if($themes["standard"]=='1') { echo '<b>Standard</b>'; } echo '</td>
         <td>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-grey own-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Velg handling <span class="caret"></span>
              </button> 
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="/editor/set.theme/'.$themes["tmp_id"].'">Sett som standard</a></li>
                <li><a href="/editor/edit.source/'.$themes["tmp_id"].'">Endre HTML/CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Historikk</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Slett og fjern</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
         </td>
         </tr>';
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your query like this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    installed_designs 
WHERE 
    u_id='$user[id]' 
ORDER BY 
    standard DESC,
    tmp_id DESC
```

I noticed you have a standard flag in your table so use two ordering rules: first by standard descending (standard will go first, then non-standards) and then by your tmp_id (if the standard value is the same this rule will be applied).

Comment: Never knew that this was possible! Thank you so much for showing me this.

Comment: That's the very basics of SQL